# JSR 303 Bean validation contraints without Annotations

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, bean-validation

We are developing REST services and want to use JSR 303 for input data validation, but problem here is all model objects are generated from groovy DSL and will be imported as jars. So there is no flexibility of writing JSR-303 annotations on top of object fields.

So is there any other alternative to use JSR-303 without annotations,is it possible by XML configuaration? or any suggestion for validation in this scenario please.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Either use the [XML configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-xml-configuration) as defined by the Bean Validation spec or - if you're working with Hibernate Validator - the API for [programmatic constraint declaration](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api).

Answer (score 3):

JSR-303 allows you to override your annotations by using XML validation descriptors. (use a validation.xml)

Comment: In META-INF you can add validation.xml, check this link